# SQLAlchemy implicit type conversion and Date validation

Tags: python, validation, types, sqlalchemy

Let's assume this model class:

```
class Person(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "person"

    date_of_birth = db.Column(db.Date)
```

With `person` being an instance of `Person`, I can do the following in my unit test:

```
person.date_of_birth = "05/05/2000"
```

So far, so good, and this code has been in production for some time. Now someone reports a bug that there are persons with dates of birth in the future. Dates of birth in the future are invalid in my context and I want to prevent them from entering the data store, so I add a validator to the model class:

```
@validates("date_of_birth")
def validate_date_of_birth(self, key, date_of_birth):
    if date_of_birth and date_of_birth > datetime.now().date():
        raise BirthDayException("A date of birth must not be in the future.")
    return date_of_birth
```

This will, somewhat understandably, break my unit test and throw an exception when I do the assignment from above:

```
>       if date_of_birth and date_of_birth > datetime.datetime.now().date():
E       TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.date'
```

I don't quite understand where I should address it, though.

- Should I change my unit test and not assign a string value to a date
  property? But there could be other places in the code where this is
  happening, leaving me exposed to regression.
- Or should I check for
  the correct data type in the validator and convert it if necessary?
- Or can I somehow tell SqlAlchemy to do the auto-conversion that it
  normally does BEFORE the validator is invoked? That would be the
  nicest solution.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: If your application is exclusively passing strings to the model constructor, why not compare with `datetime.date.today().strftime('%d/%m/%Y')`?

Comment: @snkaecharmerb thanks, this made me think in broader terms and why I am seeing a string here in the first place. The application passes date types, I am pretty sure, it is just the unit test that passes a string. But to answer this, I need to look at how we pass form data to the model in the app and whether the model should even accept a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fwiw, I ended up doing the unthinkable - check for the type and convert to date if it is a string:

```
if type(date_of_birth) is str:
    date_of_birth = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_of_birth, "%m/%d/%Y").date()

    if date_of_birth and date_of_birth > datetime.datetime.now().date():
        raise BirthDayException("A date of birth must not be in the future.")
```